# Silverlight XAML: Binding to property in EntityClass from assosiated EntityCollection (advanced?!)

Tags: xaml, binding, silverlight-4.0, path

This question relates to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841943/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-choose-which-control-to-render-based-on-bindable-at).

I have a EF model like [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2902001/images/model.png).

Using Silverlight 4 I have an application showing questions to the user, defined through the QuestionSet. If a question has more than one answer alternative, a ComboBox is rendered. If only one alternative is given, a TextBox is rendered, in which the user can put freetext.

All user answers are stored in PersonQA entities. But herein lies the question: When the TextBox is rendered, I am not able to find the correct path and bind to the property "AnswerFreetext" (in PersonQA). **What am I doing wrong?**

XAML:

> ```
>         <ListBox x:Name="QAListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectedIndex="-1" 
>              ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="5" 
>              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="10" BorderThickness="0">
>             <ListBox.Resources>
>                 <fx:EqualityToVisibilityConverter x:Key="converter"
>                     TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Collapsed" />
>                 <fx:CollectionToFirstElementConverter x:Key="collectiontoitem" />
>             </ListBox.Resources>
>             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
>                 <DataTemplate>
>                     <Grid d:DesignWidth="931" d:DesignHeight="61" d:IsLocked="True" Margin="0">
>                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                             <ColumnDefinition Width=".80*" MinWidth="800"/>
>                             <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*" MinWidth="200"/>
>                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=QuestionText}" Padding="10" FontSize="21.333" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0" Grid.Column="0" d:IsLocked="True" />
>                         <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AnswerAlternative, Mode=OneWay}" 
>                             SelectedValuePath="AnswerAlternativeId" DisplayMemberPath="AnswerText"
>                             FontSize="21.333" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Margin="60,0,0,0" d:IsLocked="True" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
>                             Visibility="{Binding Path=AnswerAlternative.Count, Converter={StaticResource converter}, ConverterParameter=2}">
>                         </ComboBox>
>                         <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="60,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=PersonQA.AnswerFreetext, Mode=TwoWay}"
>                                  Visibility="{Binding AnswerAlternative.Count, Converter={StaticResource converter}, ConverterParameter=1}" />
>                     </Grid>
>                 </DataTemplate>
>             </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
>         </ListBox>
> ```

The XAML has a ViewModel class as DataContext, which exposes **Questions** IEnumerable.

t.

Comment: Do you see any binding exception in the Output window of VS ?

Comment: 'AnswerAlternativeId' property not found on 'Question : 4' 'RIAmedlemsdatabase.Web.Models.Question' (HashCode=6114302). BindingExpression: Path='AnswerAlternativeId' DataItem='Question : 4'; target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedValuePath' (type 'System.String')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'AnswerFreetext' property not found on 'PersonQA' 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityCollection`1[RIAmedlemsdatabase.Web.Models.PersonQA]' BindingExpression: Path='PersonQA.AnswerFreetext'...

Comment: I've edited the Path-element on SelectedValuePath. Now, the above Exceptions is ALMOST gone! :)

The problem now is that the TextBox is bound to a Collection in Question-object. How do I bind to a single object property within a collection of objects? ValueConverter??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem. It solves it by looking at the problem the opposite way. By iterating on the answers in stead of the questions, I am almost there.

In addition I found that by using a ViewModelProxy-class (datacontext proxy) I am able to access the AnswerAlternative collection outside the relative binding inside the datatemplate. Read all about it here: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx